# Lower bound on the probability that a binomial variable is at least $c$-far from its expectation?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

Let $X\sim Bin(n,p)$ and $c>0$.

Confidence intervals for $X$, such as Chernoff's, have the form
$$\Pr\left[|X-np|\ge a\right]\le b.$$

I'm looking for a (nice to work with) *lower bound*.

> **Namely, how can we find $\delta_{min}$ such that**
>   $$\Pr\left[|X-np|\ge c\right]\ge \delta_{min}?$$

---

Obviously, we have $\delta_{min}=1-\sum_{i=np-c}^{np+c}{n\choose i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i}$.

Is there a nice closed-form expression that bounds this from below?

Comment: The formula you give for $\delta_{\text{min}}$ is not quite true: in particular it only holds if $np$ and $c$ are integers. Further, the powers of $i$ and $n-i$ should rather be $np + i$ and $n - np - i$.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want any scaling of $c$ with $n$? In the case where $c$ is proportional to $n$, the leading order contribution to the lower bound (and for that matter the upper bound) comes from Cramer's theorem. Where $c$ is proportional to $\sqrt{n}$, the leading order contribution comes from the central limit theorem. Where $c$ is asymptotically smaller than $\sqrt{n}$, the leading order contribution is just $1$. Here when I say "leading order" I mean in the "small parameter" $n^{-1}$.

Comment: @Ian - I don't mind scaling $c$ with $n$, or $np$.

Comment: But you want a rigorous bound for each $n$, not just an asymptotic bound?

Comment: @Ian- Ideally, I would need an explicit (non-asymptotic) bound.

Comment: This question might be of interest to you: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55585/lower-bound-for-sum-of-binomial-coefficients